# Swift automatic function inversion

Tags: swift, function, math

If I have a function like:

```
func evaluateGraph(sender: GraphView, atX: Double) -> Double? {
    return function?(atX)
}
```

Where `function` is a variable declared earlier and it is a mathematical expression (like x^2). How can I find the inverse of the univariate `function` in swift at a point (`atX`)?

Comment: This is really a math question, not a swift question.

Comment: @sbooth It is about returning the parameters of a function given the result.

Comment: @DylanModesitt Yes.  And it's a math question.  There's not a way to programmatically inverse a method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to know the inverse function in your `GraphView` (which is hopefully not infinite) you can use something like this:

```
// higher percision -> better accuracy, start...end: Interval, f: function
func getZero(#precision: Int, var #start: Double, var #end: Double, f: Double -> Double) -> Double? {

    let fS = f(start)
    let fE = f(end)     

    let isStartNegative = fS.isSignMinus
    if isStartNegative == fE.isSignMinus { return nil }

    let fMin = min(fS, fE)
    let fMax = max(fS, fE)

    let doublePrecision = pow(10, -Double(precision))

    while end - start > doublePrecision {
        let mid = (start + end) / 2
        let fMid = f(mid)
        if fMid < fMin || fMax < fMid {
            return nil
        }
        if (fMid > 0) == isStartNegative {
            end = mid
        } else {
            start = mid
        }
    }

    return (start + end) / 2
}

// same as above but it returns an array of points
func getZerosInRange(#precision: Int, #start: Double, #end: Double, f: Double -> Double) -> [Double] {

    let doublePrecision = pow(10, -Double(precision))

    /// accuracy/step count between interval; "antiproportional" performance!!!!
    let stepCount = 100.0
    let by = (end - start) / stepCount
    var zeros = [Double]()

    for x in stride(from: start, to: end, by: by) {
        if let xZero = getZero(precision: precision, start: x, end: x + by, f) {
            zeros.append(xZero)
        }
    }
    return zeros
}

// using currying; all return values should be elements of the interval start...end
func inverse(#precision: Int, #start: Double, #end: Double, f: Double -> Double)(_ x: Double) -> [Double] {
    return getZerosInRange(precision: precision, start: start, end: end) { f($0) - x }
}

let f = { (x: Double) in x * x }

// you would pass the min and max Y values of the GraphView
// type: Double -> [Double]
let inverseF = inverse(precision: 10, start: -10, end: 10, f)

inverseF(4) // outputs [-1.999999999953436, 2.000000000046564]
```

Interestingly this code rund in a playground in about 0.5 second which I didn't expect.

Comment: This is quite brilliant. I was using newtons method for finding the zeros but have switched my app to this logic. Thank you.

Comment: I've also used newtons method before but I found that it was slower in finding the zero point with `getZero`. In addition this it also resulted in many similar zero points which had to be sorted out/combined. But you should consider one problem with the current version where it cannot find zero points without conversion like of x^2. You could then use newtons method to find the exact one. I'll edit my answer if it is working.

Comment: I made an improvement for functions with poles like 1/x where it would calculate a zero point at x=0. Also the if statement is much shorter now. (see edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an inverse function to do the opposite.

So `f(x) = y` inverse `f'` gives `f'(y) = x`.

So if your defined function is to square the input then the inverse is to return the square root and so on.

You might run into trouble with something like that though as `f'(1) = 1 and -1` in the case where f(x) returns the square.

Answer (score 1):

Short of actually writing the inverse method, the only way to actually inversely infer what input gave a provided output, the best we can do is write our program to make guesses until it's within a certain accuracy.

So, for example, let's say we have the `square` function:

```
func square(input: Double) -> Double {
    return input * input
}
```

Now, if we don't want to right the inverse of this function (which actually has two inputs for any given output), then we have to write a function to guess.

```
func inverseFunction(output: Double, function: (Double)->Double) -> Double
```

This takes a `double` representing the output, and a function (the one that generated the output), and returns its best-guess at the answer.

So, how do we guess?

Well, the same way we do in pre-calculus and the early parts of any calculus 1 class.  Pick a starting number, run it through the function, compare the result to the output we're looking for.  Record the delta.  Pick a second number, run it through the function, compare the result to the output we're looking for.  Record the delta, compare it to the first delta.

Continually do this until you have minimized the delta to an acceptable accuracy level (0.1 delta okay? 0.01?  0.0001?).  The smaller the delta, the longer it takes to calculate.  But it's going to take a long time no matter what.

As for the guessing algorithm?  That's a math question that I'm not capable of answering.  I wouldn't even know where to begin with that.

**In the end, your best bet is to simply write inverse functions for any function you'd want to inverse.**